# Unable to get skrollr parallax effect on header image

Tags: javascript, css, parallax, skrollr

everyone!

So, I'm trying to implement parallax with skrollr.js. This is my first attempt and I am pulling my hair out. I've been all over the web from searching Google, YouTube and StackOverflow. I'm trying to implement a parallax effect on a header image somewhat similar to [this example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/classic.html) except the image doesn't need to be the full height of the viewport and I only need one image to have a parallax effect. I'm going for something very [similar to this](http://developers.squarespace.com/) on Squarespace's page.

I've been trying to simply use the code from the examples provided in the Skrollr.js repo. But after hours of failure, I turn to the trusty SO community!

[Here is the page](http://development.infowest.com/infowest/contact/) I have currently been testing the parallax header image on.

The classes `.scollable-between` and `.scrollable-after` are being altered on scroll but nothing is happening. Also, I am trying to implement this for mobile but I can't even scroll the page on mobile.

Any help is certainly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues:

First, position: fixed really doesn't play well with skrollr... whenever it is enabled on an element, the position relative to the scrolling element basically no longer exists, and skrollr events stop firing.

Second, it looks like the element with the background image (.parallax-image) is both being shown by the class '.skrollr-between' and also has a transform-3d property on it. When I disable the tranform3d property with the inspector, I can see the image.

It seems like you are combining two methods of parallax: Skrollr is one way of doing it via JavaScript, and CSS transforms are a way of doing it without Javascript... it would probably be best to chose one and roll with it.

Skrollr/JS method:
https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/

CSS only method:
http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback and for taking the time to help! I'm not adding anything of my own to the code you see on my page. I've been 'copy & paste'-ing from the Skrollr examples so your post really doesn't help me. I've actually already read both of those articles that you suggested. They don't teach me what I need to know or I'm just not getting it through my thick skull :O haha I've decided that I'm going to try a new solution now, without skrollr.js because it's just not making sense to me.